# How to save a modified llvm bitcode to a given filename?

Tags: c++, llvm, bitcode

I've successfully **managed to modify a given input bitcode that
was read from a file** as described [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361390/extracting-llvmmodule-from-llvmmoduleref).
Now I want to **save it to some output bitcode filename**, with
something similar to `saveIRFile(module,"myOutputBC.bc");`.
Here is the `main.cpp` file I'm using, but I can't seem to find
the proper API to do the desired save.

```
/**********************/
/* LLVM INCLUDE FILES */
/**********************/
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IRReader/IRReader.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/Support/SourceMgr.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"

/**************/
/* NAMESPACES */
/**************/
using namespace std;
using namespace llvm;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    LLVMContext ctx;
    SMDiagnostic Err;
    unique_ptr<Module> M = parseIRFile(argv[1],Err,ctx);

    if (M)
    {
        Module *module = M.get();
        for (auto
            func  = module->begin();
            func != module->end();
            func++)
        {
            errs() << func->getName() << "\n";
            // modify func's basic blocks ...
            // and save with saveIRFile(module,"myOutputBC.bc");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
std::error_code ec;
ToolOutputFile result("myOutputBC.bc", ec, sys::fs::F_None);
WriteBitcodeToFile(*module, result.os());
result.keep();
```

Note that if you're using an old version of LLVM `ToolOutputFile` may be called `tool_output_file`.

Comment: thanks, I've edited to fix some typos and now it compiles and runs.

Comment: That wasn't a typo; the class was renamed to conform to LLVM's naming conventions a few months ago (maybe it's a year already?).

Comment: Oh I'm using llvm-3.8.0 this is why ... also `WriteBitcodeToFile` accepts module rather than (*module) but I guess this too might have changed ... anyway thanks!

Comment: NP. Not sure about that * . LLVM does seem a little wobbly wrt. * and &.